# How could i comparison many rows in similarity or different in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I wanna have table with many columns fir example 4*4 so when the table become fill completely how could i comparison them row to row and rank them for they similarity (in number of cell they have in common) for users.

please if there is any template guide me to it, or if you want tell me the way say it step by step I'm new to JavaScript.

best regards

Comment: This doesn't sound like anything that would be found in a template, it's not a common thing to do.

Comment: @Dark Art, Please give an example.

Comment: for example we have a table with 6 columns and 5 rows, we need script of javascript that could comparison second row with first so it found they have 4 columns in common then 3rd row so it have 2 in common then 4th row so it have 5 in common at last then 5th row so it have 2 common columns in common with first row. the script run results should appear the table that sorted all row for similarity to first row from most to less.